# Is it possible to sort SQL result by all element of array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL, how can I sort a result set by all elements of array

I mean:

```
select * from table order by array[1] desc, array[2] desc, array[3] desc, ...
```

array - it's SQL array {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,...} and I don't know his length.

Comment: So you want to sort by all columns of the table? Because an `order by 1,2,3,4,56,7,8` will exactly be that (provided that the table *does* have 8 columns

Answer (score 1):

If you have a column which has an array type you can do an order by just as you would do for a normal column. So if the column is called foo it would become

```
select * from table order by foo desc;
```

Comment: Yes, but "order by foo" not equals "order  by foo[1], foo[2], foo[3], foo[4], etc..."

Comment: Comparison of arrays is done element by element, in what way is that different from what you are doing?

Comment: The problem is I don't size of foo array

Comment: Yes I know you don't know the size. I think doing a simple ORDER BY foo would give what you want as it does an element by element comparison figuring out how many elements there are by itself. You say it is different. Can you tell me in which way order by foo; differs from order by foo[1], foo[2], foo[3], foo[4], etc... in it's result?

Comment: It would be nice if the user who downvoted this correct answer could explain why.